# Sieve of Eratosthenes in F#

Tags: primes, f#, sieve-of-eratosthenes

after looking at the pseudocode for the Sieve of Eratosthenes on wikipedia I tried implementing a similar version using F#. The code runs just fine, that is, it returns all prime numbers up until a given number. But I was wondering if the implementation could be improved. See below for the code:

```
let rec sieve xs count maxNumb = 
    match count = maxNumb with
    | true -> xs
    | false when (Array.contains count xs) -> 
        xs
        |> Array.filter (fun ys -> ys % count <> 0. || ys = count)
        |> fun filteredArr -> sieve filteredArr (count + 1.) maxNumb
    | false -> sieve xs (count + 1.) maxNumb

let findPrimes maxNumb = 
    sieve [|2. .. maxNumb|] 2. maxNumb
```

```
findPrimes 30.

[|2.0; 3.0; 5.0; 7.0; 11.0; 13.0; 17.0; 19.0; 23.0; 29.0|]
```

Thank you in advance for any comments or remarks :)

Comment: You might be interested in [Melissa O'Neill's paper *The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes*](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) which explains how the classic Haskell one-liner is, in fact, *not* actually the Sieve of Eratosthenes, what – in her opinion – *are* the important traits of what makes program a "genuine" implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes, then shows a lazy, purely functional implementation of an algorithm that *does* exhibit the traits she defined as "genuine". While the laziness part is not directly applicable to F#, the rest is.

Comment: Thank you so much Jörg W Mittag! I just had a look at the paper, I will definitely come back with a better implementation.  :)

Answer (score 2):

One small improvement. You can remove one of the recursive calles which improves readability and enables the compiler to use tail recursion:

```
let rec sieve xs count maxNumb =        
    if count = maxNumb then xs
    else
        let xs' = if xs |> Array.contains count 
                  then xs |> Array.filter (fun ys -> ys % count <> 0. || ys = count)
                  else xs
        sieve xs' (count + 1.) maxNumb
```

Further more, I was wondering why not using a list instead of the array because lists are more "functional-like". Comparing the performance of list usage vs. array usage, the array was 10 times faster ^^.